# How can I specify a group of `*.d.ts` files?

Tags: typescript, package.json

How can I specify a group of `*.d.ts` files? In `package.json` I can set only 1 specific file or an array of them in `types`, but let's say I have a project consisting of many `.ts` files and it is unlikely I will need to write them all in package.json. My declaration files are generated by `tsc` and output to the types folder.

I tried writing `types/**/*` or `types/*` - it doesn't work, in the second project where I plug in this tsc it says there are no types and offers to download from `@types`. Perhaps there is another option solution to the problem, because I have code written in TypeScript, too, and maybe if you plug in ts code types would not be needed, but in `package.json` in `main` can specify 1 file and it clearly should be in my case `js`, because it should be possible to connect the prefect not only to the project with `ts`.

I also tried creating index.d.ts with

```
export { tee } from '/src/ride';
export { test } from '/src/test';
```

and it works, but it still requires specifying every function to be exported. There must be some simple way to export all types at once, or if the project uses ts, then connect not from `dist` but from `src`.

Comment: Export 1 file, but that file can export a number of other files.

Comment: @Evert That's what I thought and wrote it in the question
`I also tried creating index.d.ts with export { tee } from '/src/ride'; export { test } from '/src/test';` And I pointed out that this is not the best solution and there are probably better ones out there, because exporting a lot of files and functions from them is so bad. Maybe there isn't an easy option, I just recently started using TypeScript.

Comment: If there's a fixed pattern to this file, you could write a small script that generates it for you.